# DevExpress eXpressApp -- Database updates

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am currently using DevExpress's eXpressApp. I would like to know how to go about also triggering updates of the customer table, and probably a rentalHistory table when a video is rented? Do I need to do it in code? Or can I create triggers or maybe queries that can be automagically invoked when the CommitChanges() is invoked

```
 public class Rent : VideoRentBaseObject {
        MovieItem item;
        int days;
        DateTime? returnedOn;
        Receipt receipt;
        Receipt receiptOverdue;
        decimal payment;
        decimal overduePayment;

        public Rent(Session session) : base(session) { }
        public Rent(Session session, int selfId)
            : this(session) {
            SelfId = selfId;
        }
        public Rent(Receipt receipt, MovieItem item) : this(receipt, item, 0) { }
        public Rent(Receipt receipt, MovieItem item, int days)
            : this(receipt.Session) {
            if(receipt == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Receipt");
            if(item == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Item");
            if(item.Status != MovieItemStatus.Active) throw new ArgumentException("Item is not active");
            Receipt = receipt;
            Item = item;
            if(receipt.Type == ReceiptType.Purchases) {
                Item.Status = MovieItemStatus.Sold;
                Item.AvailableForSell = false;
                Days = 0;
            } else {
                Item.Status = MovieItemStatus.Rented;
                Days = days != 0 ? days : item.Movie.Category.GetPrice(item.Format).DefaultRentDays;
            }
        }
        public override void AfterConstruction() {
            base.AfterConstruction();
            Days = 1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override the method onSaving() of the Rent Class, and you can put some logic in , make changes in the associated Client object, save it, before or after save the rent changes.